# Nested filtering on Set object while using List java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Requirement is to filter a List based on the nested Set Object. I have tried anyMatch but seems it didn't working for me , ideally it should return List which does the filtering on nested Set .

Let's say i have List of Contracts Contract 1 , Contract 2.

```
Contract1 has Set<Activity> = {"START","STOP","WAIT"}

Contract2 has Set<Activity> = {"START", "STOP"}
```

So , in this case final output will List  be filtered on Activity type "START" , it should return List where Contract 1 has only START activity and same with the Contract 2.

```
**class Contract

public String name;
public Set<Activity> activities;

class Activity

private ActivityType activityType; //enum**



// method for filter list based on the activity type

List<Contract> filterOnActivityList = contractList.stream().filter(contract -> contract.getActivities().stream().anyMatch(activity -> activity.getActivityType().equals("START")))).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Do you want to return only the `Activity` whose `ActivityType` is "START" from the `activities` of a `Contract` object?

Comment: You should use filter() inside while streaming the Set<Activity> which should filter out all the Activities where the activityType is "START" and then you can collect it over

Comment: The question is very unclear. Why your classes and code at all is not properly formatted? Why do you say "*Set Object*" and not `Set<Activity>`. What do you mean with "*it should return Set object*" - what *object*? Do you realize you speak about `Set` but actually returning a `List` (using `collect(toList())`)?

Comment: @Abra , you are damn correct but i just want List<Contract> with filtered on nested Set<Activity>. I have updated my requiremnts. Thanks for you quick help.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: `List<Contract> filterOnActivityList = contractList.stream()
                .filter(contract -> contract.getActivities().stream()
                        .anyMatch(activity -> activity.getActivityType().equals(ActivityType.START)))
                .map(contract -> new Contract(contract.getName(),new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(new Activity(ActivityType.START)))))
                .collect(toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of `Contract` objects. Each `Contract` object contains a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of `Activity` objects. An `Activity` object has its `ActivityType` (where `ActivityType` is an `enum`). You want to iterate through each `Contract` in the `List` and check whether its `Set` of `Activity` contains an `Activity` whose `ActivityType` is *START* and you want to extract that `Activity` and collect all the extracted `Activity` objects into another, separate `List`.

Here is the code. It uses methods that were introduced in Java 9. (Note that I guessed and filled in a lot of gaps in the code you posted in your question, like class `Activity` and class `Contract` and `ActivityType` enum). Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Contract {
    private Set<Activity> activities;

    public Contract() {
        activities = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<Activity> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(Set<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Activity a0 = new Activity(ActivityType.OTHER);
        Activity a1 = new Activity(ActivityType.START);
        Activity a2 = new Activity(ActivityType.THAT);
        Contract c0 = new Contract();
        c0.setActivities(Set.of(a0, a1, a2));
        Activity a3 = new Activity(ActivityType.STOP);
        Activity a4 = new Activity(ActivityType.THAT);
        Activity a5 = new Activity(ActivityType.THIS);
        Activity a6 = new Activity(ActivityType.OTHER);
        Contract c1 = new Contract();
        c1.setActivities(Set.of(a3, a4, a5, a6));
        Activity a7 = new Activity(ActivityType.STOP);
        Activity a8 = new Activity(ActivityType.START);
        Contract c2 = new Contract();
        c2.setActivities(Set.of(a7, a8));
        List<Contract> contracts = List.of(c0, c1, c2);
        List<Activity> starts = contracts.stream()
                                         .flatMap(c -> c.getActivities().stream())
                                         .filter(a -> a.getActivityType().equals(ActivityType.START))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(starts);
    }
}

enum ActivityType {
    START, STOP, THIS, THAT, OTHER;
}

class Activity {
    private ActivityType activityType;

    public Activity(ActivityType type) {
        activityType = type;
    }

    public ActivityType getActivityType() {
        return activityType;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return activityType.name();
    }
}
```

In method `main()` (in above code) I create a `List` of three `Contract` objects where each object contains a different `Set` of `Activity` objects. Remember that a `Set` contains no duplicates.

The "stream" operation takes the `activities` of each `Contract` and creates a `Stream` of `Activity` (this is what the `flatMap()` method does). In other words, method `flatMap()` returns a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of `Activity` objects. That stream is filtered such that only an `Activity` whose `ActivityType` is *START* passes through the filter. Finally, each `Activity` that passes through the filter is collected into a new `List` that only contains `Activity` objects whose `ActivityType` is *START*.

The output of running the above code is

```
[START, START]
```

because there are only two such objects created.

(Now I guess you'll probably write a comment like: *That's not what I asked at all* :-)

Comment: No you have provided the correct solution , but my question framing was wrong.